# Execute different codes on ok and cancel of confirm message

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, confirm

I have a textBox and I want to create a confirm message on text_changed event and execute different codes on ok and cancel in code behind under text_changed event

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: No problem, I know it is feasible with hidden button but I don't want use of button

Answer (score 0):

window.confirm returns a boolean, in your button you could add `onclick="trigger_confirmation"`

```
var trigger_confirmation = function(){
    if(window.confirm("Are you sure blah blah blah?")){
        // user confirmed
    } else {
        // user declined
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st thing.there is no button and 2nd how to use it on code behind

Comment: You can just use the `onchange` attribute of the textbox (`onchange="trigger_confirmation"`). In fact, it actually looks like you already have a `ontextchanged` attribute...

Comment: Yes, I have ontextChanged, and in code behind I have done some coding under that event and I want to have a confirm message on ontextchanged event and execute the codes some code under yes and some under No of confirm under ontextChanged event

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your functionality you have to do following

Make AutoPostBack="True" of your text box.

Add one hidden filed and add java script like following code example in aspx page.

**Note:** java script block must be come after you hidden field and text box control.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">

                var textChange = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').getAttribute("onchange");

                document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').setAttribute("onchange", "JustConfirm();");

                function JustConfirm() {
                    var IsConfirm = confirm('Confirm event?');
                    var hdnctrl = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');
                    hdnctrl.value = IsConfirm ? 'yes' : 'no';
                    eval(textChange);
                }
</script>
```

Now in server side put code check as following

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HiddenField1.Value == "yes")
            {
                // Any c# code for confirmation
            }
            else
            {
                // Any c# code for not confirmation
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code inside your `TextBox1_TextChanged` block:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script>if(window.confirm('Press ok to continue?')){// on ok clicked  }</script>");
```