# Confirmation message in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

and my code behind code is

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string confirmValue = null;
   confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
   if (confirmValue == "No")
   {
      some code....
   }
   else
   {
     return;
   }
}
```

What actually gonig is confirmValue storing the values like `yes,No,Yes,No`.
But for first time it will show confirmation message, I will click on `Ok` button and some entries will done then I click on save button it will show again message box at this time I will click on `Cancel` button then it will go into the if condition but confirmvalue is storing First clicked yes and Next time clicked no so it is going into else condition ....

what i have to do please help me b

Comment: Exact same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112536/execute-different-codes-in-code-behind-on-confirm-ok-and-cancel probably worth checking it out

Comment: I want to show confirmation when clicking button save. If he left any data to enter.that's why i had added it in "OnClientClick"

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to simply use the "OnClientClick" property of the button control like so:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to save data?');"
```

If the user clicks "No" then the button event will never fire...  You don't need any of that other stuff.